# Web Application - Deleting parent also delete direct and indirect dependents

Tags: java, web-applications

What is the approach in handling big hierarchy of parent and children relationship?

Let say I would like to delete a parent via a web application, deleting this parent should also delete all dependents. The issue here is due to performance and possibility on the database lock during the processing of the mass number of children

How usually the solution of such scenario is handled and designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best solution I can think of is this:**

**1)** Create your `Tables` schema which defines `Primary-Foreign keys`.

**2)** Create **stored-procedures** which deal with **update/delete** of the data.

**3)** Call these **stored-procedures** from your `java program`. This will be 1 straight call to Database. You will be **handing over the control** from `Java Program` to `Database`.

**4)** Now, from your **stored-procedure**, either you **delete** records *manually* or **delete cascade**. **Delete cascade** deletes ***all child records*** automatically upon `deleting` ***parent record***.

**5)** Remember, you will have to implement your *foreign key* with `ON DELETE CASCADE` command to use cascade delete option.